# VS 2010 Problems Referencing COM Objects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssis

I'm trying to create a SSIS project with a Script Task that uses Visual Basic Code.
In it, I'm trying to use the Microsoft Scripting Runtime COM object. My VS 2010 has installed the .NET 4.5 Framework but whenever I try to add the Reference it comes with this problem:

[image]

*Edit #2: Visual Studio actually pops up an error:
[image]

After checking the References Properties of the Project, the Path says: "The System cannot find the reference path". Even then you can manually reach it yourself.

Upon further investigation I found that ALL COM objects encounter the same issue:

[image]

I have seen a number of solutions pointing to a re-install of Visual Studio and the like. Which I have done with no success.

Does anyone have an idea of what could be causing the problem?

*Edit: I think it bears to point, i have tried some funny business with the Interop (setting it to true and to false does nothing). I saw some answers online but this made no difference.

Comment: Please explain what is wrong. Your graphics are not nearly as self-explanatory as you are assuming.

Comment: also post the error that is being spit out by VS

Comment: @RBarryYoung Sorry about that, I added the error prompt that came up as well as the reference problem code that appears under the Project Properties > References. I hope that helps.

Comment: I don't think that you can normally add COM references/projects to a .Net Solution, can you?  Don't you have to use an Interop instead?